# Play framework + Ebean: [error] ... not found: type Finder

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, ebean

I developed a java application in Play 2.0 and now I am trying to deploy it to AWS. I am first trying to run it the same way as I did on my local computer. I copied the play sources to the virtual EC2 server (Ubuntu 12.04), exported play to classpath, and copied my project. When I run play compile, I get the following error

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples/java/test-crud/project
[info] Set current project to computer-database (in build file:/home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples/java/test-crud/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples/java/test-crud/}computer-database...
[info] Done updating.                                                                  
[info] Compiling 21 Scala sources and 16 Java sources to /home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples  /java/test-crud/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples/java/test-crud/app/models/Dealership.java:32: not found: type Finder
[error]     public static Finder<Long,Dealership> find = new Finder<Long,Dealership>(Long.class, Dealership.class); 
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/home/ubuntu/play-2.0/samples/java/test-crud/}computer-database/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 117 s, completed Apr 21, 2014 3:48:33 AM
```

The application is built on the CRUD example with Ebean. When I try to compile that sample application in Play, I do not have any troubles. Why does the compiler have issues with Finder?

Comment: Does Dealership extend play.db.ebean.Model?  If it doesn't, you'll need to declare it as Model.Finder.

Comment: I had the same thing happen, I was extending Model, but after adding import import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder; it went away. And didn't come back after I removed the import.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been happening to me sporadically, some times it compiles, sometimes not.

I fixed it by changing `Finder` to the more specific `Model.Finder`.

Your line becomes:

```
public static Model.Finder<Long,Dealership> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Dealership>(Long.class, Dealership.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the compilation result was depending on order files were compiled. And I could not deploy the application.
I can't explain why, but I solve it removing the use of finder in views.

There is an example of what to do, try to replace in view :

index.scala.html

```
@for(dealer <- Dealership.find.all()) {
  ...
}
```

with

```
@(dealerships: List[Dealership])
...
@for(dealer <- dealerships) {
...
}
```

and add in your controller :

```
public class Dealerships extends Controller {
  public Result index() {
     return ok (index.render (Dealership.find.all()));
  }
}
```